# How do I convert 0000 to an array? in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 function validate(pin){
      return pin. to.String().split(' ');
    }

    console.log(validate(000)) // ['0'] I want the output to be like this ['0','0','0']
    console.log(validate(01))  // ['1'] I want the output to be like this ['0','1']
```

i want to return the output to be like this ['0','0','0'] but its giving me this ['0']

Comment: Can you please show your current code?

Comment: how is 0001 stored, is it a string? if it is a string then answer provided by @Sascha will work. Can you show your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!, please provide your work on it. This will resolve your queries in the context of your program.

Comment: that is my code there sir @The Grand J and Puneet Shekhawat hope you help me solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you have a number, and you always want 4 digits, with padding on the left of zeros when there are less than 4, convert it to a string and use `.padStart()`.

```js
const n = 1;
const s = n.toString().padStart(4, "0");
console.log(s);

const a = s.split('');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: but my parameter or arguments is not fixed and if i convert this for example 00912 it will give me a '912' instead i want like this ['0','0','9','1','2']

Comment: @babyama: Numbers are not strings. In your updated question, you wrote `000` and `01`. Think about them mathematically. What numbers are they? They're just `0` and `1`. The syntax you're using adds unnecessary leading zeros to create the `0` and the `1`, but resulting number in the program doesn't have any knowledge of the syntax you used to create it.